# Explicit Hamel basis of real numbers

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Is there an explicit construction of a Hamel basis of the  vector space of real numbers $\mathbb R $ over the field of rational numbers $\mathbb Q $?

Comment: Given that the existence of a Hamel basis requires some amount of the Axiom of Choice, I don't think any construction of such a basis can be called entirely "explicit." Does the usual proof that such a basis exists - involving a well-ordering of the reals - not satisfy your criterion for "explicit definition?"

Comment: Noah, different well-orderings of $\mathbb{R}$ may have different descriptive set-theoretic complexities. It's not like every well-order is an enigma that we cannot understand. Some models of set theory have relatively tame well-orders of $\mathbb{R}$, others do not. So the question can be taken as: what is the descriptive set-theoretic complexity of a Hamel basis. The answer is highly independent of ZFC, but settled by large cardinals.

Comment: While Joel has found an interesting way to interpret the question, I think this says more about his version than about the original.

Comment: @Joel: I was aware of that, and it's a fair point. I'm just not sure that $\Delta^1_2$ satisfies (my, at least) intuitive notion of "explicit," especially when "explicit" is modifying "construction." To be fair, if I understand the result correctly, we *can* construct a pair of formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $\phi$ is $\Pi^1_2$, $\psi$ is $\Sigma^1_2$, and (under some set-theoretic assumptions) we have that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent and define a well-ordering of the reals, so that may constitute an explicit construction?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to be contentious. Many people take "explicit" to mean Borel, especially in descriptive set theory, so in that sense of the word, the answer to the OP's uestion is negative. But to my mind, a $\Delta^1_2$ set is still comparatively explicit (obtained from a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by projecting, complement, projection), as is indeed any projective set, and in this case, the answer is independent of ZFC. But if you believe in large cardinals, then the answer again is negative, even with this more generous projective understanding of explicit.

Comment: @Noah.  That EVERY vector space has a Hamel basis requires some version of AC.  But this is one _particular_ space.

Comment: Michael, you need at least some AC for this space, since it is consistent with ZF (assuming some amount of consistency) that there is no Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, as the existence of such a basis implies the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set.

Answer (score 34):

It is consistent with the axioms of ZFC that there is a
Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with
complexity $\Delta^1_2$ in the descriptive set theoretic
hierarchy. This is true, for example, in the constructible
universe $L$, where there is a $\Delta^1_2$ well-ordering
of the reals, as I explain in [this MO
answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5303/basis-of-linfinity/8647#8647),
which is closely related to this question. Complexity $\Delta^1_2$ is a surprisingly low complexity, since such a set (and its complement) can both be obtained by starting with a certain closed set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, projecting it to $\mathbb{R}^2$, taking the complement, and projecting down to $\mathbb{R}$, and so it would seem to count as fairly explicit.

Meanwhile, there can never be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$
over $\mathbb{Q}$ that is Borel, that is, with complexity
$\Delta^1_1$, since from any Borel Hamel basis one can produce a
non-Lebesgue measurable set of the same complexity by the Vitali argument (remove
an element, take the span of the other elements, and
consider its cosets). But of course every Borel set is
Lebesgue measurable.

At the same time, it is a consequence of the existence of large
cardinals that every projective set of reals is Lebesgue
measurable, and in this case, there can be no projective
Hamel basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, again by the Vitali argument. The
projective hierarchy of sets arises by closing the Borel
sets under continuous images, as well as complements,
countable unions and intersections. Thus, in such a
situation, there can be no easily-described Hamel basis for
$\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: OK, what is the closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$? (sorry for being such a jerk...)

Comment: Sheikraisin, the construction is only guaranteed to work in the set-theoretic universe $L$, and the description of the well-order (and hence the Hamel basis) makes use of the detailed structure of that universe (so it won't really be comprehensible without knowledge of the structure of $L$). The closed set corresponds to the real-quantifier free part $\psi(x,y,z)$ of the $\Sigma^1_2$ description $\varphi(x)\iff\exists y\forall z\ \neg\psi(x,y,z)$. We may assume that $\psi$ has complexity $\Pi^0_1$, which means it describes a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I think you and I are using different definitions of the word "explicit".  There isn't any pornography made by logicians, is there?

Comment: Oh yes, there is some here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity and here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/what-are-some-reasonable-sounding-statements-that-are-independent-of-zfc and here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11540/…. 

Answer (score 15):

If you have such a basis, you also have a subspace of co-dimension 1, and this turns out to be a [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set.), that is quite a non-constructible object. For details, e.g. check [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets/23206#23206).

Answer (score 15):

Arnie Miller has shown that if V=L then one can do a bit better than what Joel said; there will be a $\Pi^1_1$ Hamel basis for the reals over the rationals.  The reference is "Infinite combinatorics and definability," Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 41 (1989) 179-203.  This paper also improves the complexity bound from $\Delta^1_2$ to $\Pi^1_1$ for several other constructions under the hypothesis V=L.

Comment: Is this a general method whenever there is a $\Delta^1_2$ well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$, or does it use more of the $V=L$ hypothesis?

Comment: @Andreas: I read Miller's paper years ago, so I do not remember the details. Do you know if, from his techniques, similar results can be obtained higher up in the projective hierarchy starting with suitable versions of K?

Comment: @Andres: I don't remember the details, but I think Arnie's central idea here was to (recursively) code levels of the L hierarchy into the Hamel base.  On the one hand, coding becomes easier higher in the hierarchy, but on the other hand you'll have to code more complicated things (like mice).  My guess is that the benefits at least match the burdens, so that the construction will continue to work, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks! I'm (re)reading the paper now.

Comment: I'm confused.  Suppose $A$ is a $\Pi_1^1$ Hamel basis.  
It seems to me that:

* with out loss of generality we may assume 1 is in $A$.

* Let $B$ be the rational span of $A\setminus\{1\}$, then $B$ is
still $\Pi_1^1$. Hence, Lebesque measurable.

* Every real can be uniquely written as the sum of an element of $B$ plus a rational. But then the Vitali argument tell us $B$ is
no measurable.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Dave, isn't your set $B$ actually $\Sigma^1_2$? That is, $z\in B$ iff $\exists \vec x\in A$ such that $z$ is rational linear combination of $\vec x$. 

Answer (score 3):

Re Andreas' comment, I have a writeup of a generalization of Miller's result:  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/talks_kiel.pdf

Comment: I think you should be commended for using "writeup" in the literal sense! I will also join others in warmly welcoming you to MO!

Comment: Haha! Thank you :)