# Is a measurable homomorphism on a Lie group smooth?

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, pr.probability

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and let $\mathcal B(G)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose that $f : G \to G$ is a Borel-measurable homomorphism. Is $f$ smooth?

---

**Edit:** My original question said "measurable function" instead of the more accurate "measurable homomorphism." Marc Palm and other people answered both questions very nicely:

- there are obviously non-smooth measurable functions on Lie groups, and
- all measurable homomorphisms on Lie groups are smooth.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question: is every measurable cocycle
cphomplogous to a smooth one?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57426/are-there-any-non-linear-solutions-of-cauchys-equation-fxyfxfy-with/57532#57532

Comment: Whatever theorem you want to prove about Lie groups should hold at least for the Lie group $\mathbb R$, right?

Comment: Tom, did you mean to say function, or did you mean homomorphism? 

Comment: *handslap.* Of course, homomorphism.

Comment: A new, improved question.  Making the existing comments and answers seem nonsensical...

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: good point, and thanks very much for pointing out the discrepancy. I've made a clarifying edit to the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, take a proper closed set $X$ and define $f|X = 1$ and $f|G-X = g \neq 1$.

If you consider $f$ to be a group homomorphism, then the answer is yes in general.

Comment: See here for example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms

Comment: The counterexample works if X is not open. Taking X as the connected component of the identity wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Palm. I meant homomorphism but I foolishly neglected to say it. Why is the answer yes in general? Intuitively, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains all the topological information of the space, hence the differential information since $G$ is a Lie group. However, this is just heuristic speculation and I don't know a good argument which makes this fact apparent.

Comment: Excellent, I just looked at your other question. Alain Varette provides a nice reference to Adam Kleppner's paper. A measurable homomorphism of locally compact groups is continuous. Since Lie groups are locally compact, this proves it.

Direct link to Alain Varette's answer:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms/64140#64140

Comment: And André Henriques provides the very nice intuition: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64116/are-measurable-automorphism-of-a-locally-compact-group-topological-automorphisms/64145#64145

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is interesting to know that for group cocycles the answer is in general no (even up to coboundaries). For instance the extension $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is described by a 2-cocycle $S^1 \times S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}$ that is measurable, but this cannot be chosen to be smooth or continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you impose some algebraic structure on your function $f$, like $f$ is a homomorphism, no? Since your question reminds me similar results on the additive measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. It's a great comment, but a comment nonetheless. 

Comment: Dear Todd, you are right. I fact, it was the first time I made a comment, so sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Not every measurable function on the real line is continuous, let along smooth.  Real line is a perfectly nice Lie group.