# Finding non convex functions satisfying a weak form of convexity, without the axiom of choice

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, convexity, axiom-of-choice, continuity

If a real-valued function $f$ over reals satisfies $$ (1) \; \; \; f({x+y\over2})\le {f(x)+f(y)\over2},  $$and it is continuous, then it is not hard to see that $f$ is indeed convex. On the other hand, a discontinuous additive function, which exists by the axiom of choice, satisfies (1) but is not convex.

My question is, can we find real-valued functions over reals satisfying (1) which are not convex, without using the axiom of choice? Or, are there models of set theory in which all functions satisfying (1) are convex (continuous)?

Comment: There is some related discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876410/an-explicit-construction-for-an-everywhere-discontinuous-real-function-with-f  which in particular mentions a model of set theory where such functions are convex.

Comment: (+1) Nice question, Mohammad! I doubt if one can find a proof for this theorem without using (any degree of) Axiom of Choice. By the way, can you add some explanations about the motivation for building a model of $ZF+\neg AC$ in which all (continuous or discontinuous) functions which satisfy the condition (1) are convex? Does it have any application in your work or any particular interpretation, say in physics, analysis or statistics? Or this is just a question out of curiosity?

Comment: somehow related question: [Are there any non-linear solutions of Cauchy's equation (f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)) without assuming the Axiom of Choice?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57426/are-there-any-non-linear-solutions-of-cauchys-equation-fxy-fxfy-wit?rq=1).

Comment: @Suvrit, Thanks a lot. That actually answers my question.

Comment: @Amir, I'm working on some problems in convex analysis right now, but this question was more out of curiosity than for any particular application.

Comment: @suvrit Why not post an answer?

Comment: @YemonChoi to be fair to the original author on the answer on m.SE, I've requested him to post his answer on MO. If he does not post, then I'll post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one posted the answer mentioned in the comments, I write it here to make this question more helpful.

In the Solovay model of set theory, where the axiom of choice does not hold, all functions are measurable; and this implies that all functions satisfying (1) are convex by a theorem of Sierpinski.

Comment: Can you give a reference to Sierpinski's paper, or another source where the result and its proof can be found?

Comment: @Nate, The Wikipedia article on convex functions gives this reference: http://books.google.com/books?id=P30Y7daiGvQC&pg=PA12

Comment: @NateEldredge Some further references are mentioned [in my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/midpoint-convex-and-continuous-implies-convex/83398#83398). (Including the references to the papers by Sierpinski and Blumberg.)